# How do I get the closest match vlookup for entire column in Google Big Query SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to take a column of original prices and enter a discount % and return the closest match to a predetermined set of values. These allowable values are found in another table that is just one column of prices. I am curious to hear how ties would be handled. Please note that this is for a long list of items, so this would have to apply to an entire column. The specific syntax needed is Google Big Query.

I envision this functioning similarly to excel's VLOOKUP approximate = 1. In practice, I will apply the same solution to multiple price points in the results table (ex. origPrice, 25%off, 50%off, and 75%off etc. ), but I figured that I could copy-paste the solution multiple times.

The below example shows a 50% price reduction.

**allowableDiscounts**

| discountPrice |
| --- |
| $51.00 |
| $48.50 |
| $40.00 |

**productInfo**

| Item | OrigPrice |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | $100.00 |
| Banana | $ 98.00 |

**Desired Output**

| Item | OrigPrice | exact50off | closestMatch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | $100.00 | $50.00 | $51.00 |
| Banana | $ 98.00 | $44.00 | $40.00 |

I have researched solutions here and elsewhere. Most of what I found suggested sorting the allowableDiscounts table by the absolute value of the difference between exact50off and discountPrice. That worked great for one instance, but I could not figure out how to apply that to an entire list of prices.

I have workarounds both in SQL and excel that can accomplish the same task manually, but I am looking for something to match the above function so that way if the allowableDiscounts table changes, the calculations will reflect that without recoding.

```
SELECT
   p.Item,
   p.OrigPrice,
   p.OrigPrice * 0.5 AS exact50off
   --new code from allowableDiscounts.discountPrice
FROM
   productInfo AS p
WHERE
   --filters applied as needed
```

Comment: What's the data type for the field "*OrigPrice*"?

Comment: @lemon all numbers are FLOATs, sorry I will edit the post to include decimals!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may work it out with a `CROSS JOIN`, then compute the smallest difference and filter out the other generated records (with higher differences).

Smallest difference here is retrieved by assigning a rank to all differences in each partition <Item, OrigPrice> (with [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions#row_number)), then all values ranked higher than 1 are discarded.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           OrigPrice*0.5 AS exact50off,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Item, OrigPrice ORDER BY ABS(discountPrice - OrigPrice*0.5)) AS rn
    FROM productInfo
    CROSS JOIN allowableDiscounts
)
SELECT Item, 
       OrigPrice, 
       exact50off,
       discountPrice
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Please be careful with `cross join`, the question asked for "long list of items". So if there are several 1000 entries in allowableDiscounts, addional memory needs to be allocated and this can lead to a stop of the query.

Comment: Thank you, this is great. I need to dive a little deeper into `WITH`, `PARTITION`, `OVER`, and `CROSS` joins, but I'm following the gist of your explanation.

For multiple discount price points, would I be able to duplicate the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER`... line under a new alias and adjust the `WHERE` clause to be `WHERE rn = 1 OR rn2 = 1` or would you recommend duplicating this whole code and using `JOIN` on subqueries?

Comment: Agreed Samuel. @TheTravdrum If you can make a sample of what you mean by updating your post, I may follow up with an update of the answer.

Comment: Thank you both. The discount price list is only around 200 entries, but the item could be >10,000 depending on the filters applied. @lemon the post update only referred to adding the hundredth place decimals to all numbers to represent FLOATs. The concept is still the same

Comment: the discount price list is also sorted ascending if that helps speed things up.

Comment: I've just seen your updated comment, it's better to use two row_number inside the same query and having `WHERE rn = 1 OR rn2 = 1` rather than having two duplicated codes, given both solutions work for you. @TheTravdrum

Answer (score 1):

In case the tables are large, as you stated, a cross join is not possible and a window function is the only solution.

First we generate a function `nearest`, which return the element (x or y) closest to  a target value.

Then we define both tables, discountPrice and productInfo. Next, we union these tables as `helper`. The first `column` `tmp` holds the value `1`, if the data is from the main table `productInfo` and we calculate the column `exact50off`. For the table discountPrice the `tmp` column in set to `0` and the `exact50off` column is filled with the entries `discountPrice`. We add the table  discountPrice  again, but for column exact75off.

We query the `helper` table and use:

```
last_value(if(tmp=0,exact50off,null) ignore nulls) over (order by exact50off),
```

- `tmp=0` : Keep only entries from the table discountPrice
- `last_value` get nearest lowest value from table discountPrice

We run the same again, but with `desc` to obtain the nearest highest value.

The function `nearest` yields the nearest values of both.

Analog this is done for `exact75off`

```sql
create temp function nearest(target any type,x any type, y any type) as (if(abs(target-x)>abs(target-y),y,x) );

with allowableDiscounts as (select * from  unnest([51,48.5,40,23,20]) as discountPrice ),
productInfo as (select "Apple" as item, 100 as OrigPrice union all select "Banana",98 union all select "Banana cheap",88),

helper as (
  select 1 as tmp, # this column holds the info from which table the rows come forme
  item,OrigPrice, # all columns of the table productInfo (2)
  OrigPrice/2 as exact50off, # calc 50%
  OrigPrice*0.25 as exact75off, # calc 75%
   from  productInfo
  
  union all # table for 50%
  select 0 as tmp, 
  null,null, # (2) null entries, because the table productInfo has two columns (2)
  discountPrice as exact50off, #possible values for 50% off
  null # other calc (75%)
  from  allowableDiscounts 

  union all # table for 75%
  select 0 as tmp, 
  null,null, # (2) null entries, because the table productInfo has two columns (2)
  null, # other calc (50%)
  discountPrice, #possible values for 75% off  
  from  allowableDiscounts 
  
  )

  select *,
  nearest(exact50off,
  last_value(if(tmp=0,exact50off,null) ignore nulls) over (order by exact50off),
  last_value(if(tmp=0,exact50off,null) ignore nulls) over (order by exact50off desc)
  ) as  closestMatch50off,
  nearest(exact75off,
  last_value(if(tmp=0,exact75off,null) ignore nulls) over (order by exact75off),
  last_value(if(tmp=0,exact75off,null) ignore nulls) over (order by exact75off desc)
  ) as  closestMatch75off,

  from helper
 qualify tmp=1
  order by exact50off
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I will have to dig into everything going on here between other work projects, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the ABS(X) function to compute the absolute values between the columns in the tables to make a match as an exact match or a difference in values between 1 and 4 for the various discount values as below, use a LEFT JOIN to get allow values in your leading table productInfo and either matching values or NULL from the allowableDiscounts table.

```
SELECT
   p.Item,
   p.OrigPrice,
   p.OrigPrice * 0.5 AS exact50off,
   p.OrigPrice * 0.25 AS exact25off,
   p.OrigPrice * 0.75 AS exact75off,
   q.discountPrice AS closestMatch
FROM
   productInfo AS p
LEFT JOIN allowableDiscounts q on ABS(p.OrigPrice * 0.50 - q.discountPrice) = 0
OR ABS(p.OrigPrice * 0.50 - q.discountPrice) BETWEEN 0.01 AND 4.0
OR ABS(p.OrigPrice * 0.25 - q.discountPrice) = 0
OR ABS(p.OrigPrice * 0.75 - q.discountPrice) = 0 
OR ABS(p.OrigPrice * 0.25 - q.discountPrice) BETWEEN 0.01 AND 4.0
OR ABS(p.OrigPrice * 0.75 - q.discountPrice) BETWEEN 0.01 AND 4.0;
```

Comment: Sorry, this will not work. Think of a price of 80.02, then exact50off will be 40.01. The allowed discountPrice is  40.00, but this is not mached, because 80.02*0.50 - 40.00 is 0.01. This does not matches `=0` and not `BETWEEN 1 AND 4`. It can also happen, that several entries are matched and not only the nearest one.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting this

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach

```
create temp function vlookup(data array<float64>, key float64) 
returns string language js as r'''
  closestMatch = null;
  closestDifference = Number.MAX_VALUE;

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    difference = Math.abs(data[i] - key);
    if (difference < closestDifference) {
      closestMatch = data[i];
      closestDifference = difference;
    }
  }
  return closestMatch;
''';
with priceOffList as (
  select *
  from unnest([25, 50, 75]) off
)
select * from (
  select Item, OrigPrice,  off, offPrice, vlookup(arr, offPrice) as closestMatch
  from productInfo,(select array_agg(discountPrice order by discountPrice) arr from allowableDiscounts), priceOffList
  ,unnest([OrigPrice * off / 100]) as offPrice
)
pivot (any_value(offPrice) offPrice, any_value(closestMatch) closestMatch for off in (25, 50, 75))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this alternative solution, this also has some functions that I'll have to research for homework!